# How can I switch the default map to UI in order to pause the game?

Tags: unity, c#, input

I've recently set up the new Input System using Player Input component and invoke unity events. I just have one problem; I want to change the default action map to UI whenever I press the defined pause buttons because pausing won't work when the defualt map is set to Player. I want to do this via code and in `PauseInput` function. I tried using `playerInput.SwitchCurrentActionMap` but it didn't work for me. Also, I don't use a generated c# script for the player inputs. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's my pause menu code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public PlayerInput playerInput;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
    
    public void OnPause(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {
      if (context.phase == InputActionPhase.Performed) {

          if (GameIsPaused) {
              Resume();
          } else {
             Pause();
          }
     }
}

    public void Resume()
    {
        playerInput.SwitchCurrentActionMap("Player");
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }

   public void Pause ()
    {
        playerInput.SwitchCurrentActionMap("UI");
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }
}
```

[image]
As you can see, I want to change the default map from Player to UI whenever the pause button is pressed and switch back to Player whenever the button is pressed again (resume); because there can only be one active map at a time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you've edited your question. What results do you observe with this revised code?

Comment: Yes, I stored the component in a variable and put the names in double quotation marks. I assigned all the references in the inspector and checked the events of player input to see if it is assigned or not. Still it doesn't work. Also, the weird thing here is that even if I manully set "UI" as the default map, the pause menu doesn't get activated after pressing the escape button.

Comment: Show us how you configured the Events section of your PlayerInput component.

Comment: I updated the question. Can this problem be related to the fact that I don't use generated C# script for the input action asset? As far as I know, there are two ways for implementing the new input system. First is generating that script and using `OnEnable()` and `OnDisable()` and the other way is much easier, using player input component and Unity events. All of my other inputs work properly using this way but I always think this might not be right and could cause some problems.

Comment: You failed to mention that this script causes Unity to hang and report a stack overflow. That's important information. Never leave the symptoms of the problem unstated in your question - "doesn't work" is *never* enough information to troubleshoot with.

Comment: I didn't mention that because Unity didn't hang. The only thing I remember is that I got 3 or 4 errors related to stack overflow and wanted to mention it in my question but after I played the game again, I didn't get those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the callbacks get called for multiple distinct reasons, indicated by the `phase` member of the action and its context:

- **Started**: when interaction with the control begins (eg. the start of a hold/tap)
- **Performed**: when the action has been triggered (eg. pressing a button)
- **Canceled**: when the action has ended or been aborted (eg. if the player releases the button, or if the action map changes while the button is held)

So when the player presses the pause button, the following things happen:

1. `OnPause` gets called with `phase = InputActionPhase.Started`
2. You switch the action map before pausing the game.
3. Switching the action map disables the "Player" version of this control and enables the "UI" version, so `OnPause` immediately gets called with `phase = InputActionPhase.Canceled`.
4. You switch the action map before pausing the game.
5. Switching the action map disables the "UI" version of this control and enables the "OnPause" version, so `OnPause` immediately gets called with `phase = InputActionPhase.Canceled`.
6. We're back to step 2 again, and we loop steps 2-5 indefinitely. We never get to finish running the `Pause` method, because it keeps getting interrupted to send another cancelled message, leaving half-finished calls on the stack until we overflow.

So, make sure you check to see if the action is being *performed* before you act on it, so that you don't loop endlessly cancelling actions.

```
public void OnPause(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {
    if {context.phase == InputActionPhase.Performed) {

        if (GameIsPaused) {
            Resume();
        } else {
            Pause();
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to wire up your `UnityEvents` for both the Player and UI maps. That is, both your Player and UI maps should contain a "Pause/Unpause" action whose `UnityEvent` calls `OnPause`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the function to the one that you wrote and assigned the references but still the pause menu game object doesn't get activated. I couldn't find the root of the problem but I continue trying. I do my best to describe all the symptoms. I tried all possible situations for the UI events and noticed that after manually making it the default map, the escape button works and pause activates but only once and after that, it doesn't work anymore. Also, in this situation, the `Player` map doesn't work when the game starts until after pausing the game.

Comment: Want to edit your question to show how you configured your Player events in the inspector? You kept that part hidden the last time I asked.

Comment: I don't see a Pause action in the Player map. How do you plan to invoke the OnPause callback while using this map?

Comment: No, `OnPause` is in the UI map. I added an image of that. The whole point of changing the map is to access that callback which is in a different action map.

Comment: When you're in the UI, you call OnPause in the UI map to unpause. When you're not in the UI, in the Player map, you need an action you can trigger to pause. It won't call actions from the UI map when the Player map is active.

Comment: Oh, I see. So it won't call actions this way. What kind of action should I add to the Player map? Like another OnPause? How can it trigger the actual OnPause function? I would appreciate it if you answer these questions in the posted answer.

Comment: "That is, both your Player and UI maps should contain a "Pause/Unpause" action whose UnityEvent calls OnPause"

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem. I didn't know that I needed another "Pause" action in the Player map.